# I installed beautiful-atoms with pip but it cannot find blender

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-22.04, blender

There is this nice [python module](https://pypi.org/project/batoms/) to render [beautiful atoms](https://github.com/beautiful-atoms/beautiful-atoms-api) using [Blender's Python API](https://pypi.org/project/bpy/)

I installed everything using `pip` on Ubuntu 22 LTS without problems

```
>> pip install bpy
>> pip install batoms
```

When I try simple example:

```
# from https://beautiful-atoms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/python.html
from ase.build import molecule
#from batoms_api import render  # original
from batoms import render       # modified since pip package is called batoms 
atoms = molecule("H2O")
render_input = {"viewport": [1, 1, 0], "engine": "cycles", "output": "h2o.png",}
render(atoms, render_input=render_input)
```

I get following errors:

Assuming `bpy` from pip has its own `blender` installation, I get:

```
>>> from ase.build import molecule
>>> from batoms import render
>>> atoms = molecule("H2O")
>>> render_input = {"viewport": [1, 1, 0], "engine": "cycles", "output": "h2o.png",}
>>> render(atoms, render_input=render_input)
sh: 1: blender: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/prokop/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/batoms/api/__init__.py", line 21, in render
    raise OSError('Command ' + cmd +
OSError: Command blender -b  -P /home/prokop/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/batoms/api/apirun.py failed with error code 32512
```

When I link blender binary from `~/SW/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/blender` to system PATH I get this error:

```
>>> from batoms import render
>>> render(atoms, render_input=render_input)
Blender 3.4.1 (hash 55485cb379f7 built 2022-12-20 00:46:45)
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prokop/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/batoms/api/apirun.py", line 1, in <module>
    from batoms.batoms import Batoms
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'batoms'
```

So what I think I need is:

- either tell `batoms` where is the `bpy` version of blender
- or install `batoms` into `~/SW/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/blender`
- maybe I can link `blender` binary from inside pip's `bpy` module? But I don't know where to find it.

but I did not found any example how to do that

I in the [docs](https://beautiful-atoms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is recommended using anaconda, but I really don't like anaconda approach to duplicate python environment whenever I install a new package. I want to have everything together in single environemnt.

Answer (score 0):

Each Blender version has a bundled Python (version 3.10.8 for Blender 3.4). Blender only works well with the right Python version. Even though Blender can use the system Python package by `--python-use-system-env`, better not do this to avoid crashing.

Beautiful atoms is an addon for Blender. It should be installed into the addon folder of Blender, and it uses the bundled Python from Blender. However, some advanced features of beautiful-atoms depends on several packages (e.g. `spglib`, `openbabel`) which can not install correctly using `pip` inside the bundled Python, thus, a Conda Python environment with the correct version is created to replace the bundled Python, then the dependencies are installed inside this Conda enviroment. Beautiful-atoms provides a cross-platform script install.py to automate the installation and the default setup. If you don't want to use Conda, you can install it manually. https://beautiful-atoms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/installing/index.html#manual-installation. In this case, packages like `openbabel` will not be installed, but most functions of beautiful-atoms should work anyway.

The module `batoms` is an old version and is not work anymore. The `bpy` module is also a test Python module for Blender. The following installation does not work and is not suggested.

```
pip install bpy
pip install batoms
```